# How to keep printing on the same line after the progress bar using tqdm?

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

I have two nested loops, each with a progress bar. In each loop, multiple functions are run which take a long time to complete. I like to see in which state the current loop is in right now by logging it after the progress bars without breaking them.

This was the best I could come up with by creating another instance of `tqdm` and setting the `desc` of it as my desired print output.

```py
class tqdm_print():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.progress_bars: List[tqdm] = list()

    def print(self, str: str):
        lines = str.split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            pbar = tqdm(desc=line, bar_format='{desc}', leave=False)
            self.progress_bars.append(pbar)

    def close(self):
        for pbar in self.progress_bars:
            pbar.close()

    def __call__(self, str: str):
        self.print(str)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.close()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

for subject in tqdm(range(10), desc="Subjects:"):
    for session in tqdm(range(20), desc="Session:",leave=False):
        with tqdm_print() as tqdmprint:
            tqdmprint.print("foo is running")
            foo()
            tqdmprint.print("bar is running")
            bar()
```

```console
Subjects:  20%|██████████████████                                                                        | 2/10 [00:04<00:17,  2.18s/it]
Sessions: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:02<00:00,  9.19it/s] 
foo is running...
```

```console
Subjects:  20%|██████████████████                                                                        | 2/10 [00:04<00:17,  2.18s/it]
Sessions: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:02<00:00,  9.19it/s] 
foo is running...
bar is running...
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Prefeberely without using another instance of `tqdm` since the cursor keeps glitching from line to line which doesn't really cause any problem but it just looks kinda ugly.

Answer (score 0):

The bits that you need in the print statement are:

- `end='\r'`
- `flush=True`

i do this which works nicely:

```
import time

def print_progressbar(total, current, barsize=60):
    progress = int(current*barsize/total)
    completed = str(int(current*100/total)) + '%'
    print('[', chr(9608)*progress, ' ', completed, '.'*(barsize-progress), '] ', str(current)+'/'+str(total), sep='', end='\r', flush=True)



total = 600
barsize = 60
print_frequency = max(min(total//barsize, 100), 1)
print("Start Task..")
for i in range(1, total+1):
    time.sleep(0.0001)
    if i%print_frequency == 0 or i == 1:
        print_progressbar(total, i, barsize)
print("\nFinished")
```

or this which is quicker to implement and **does not** require an import:

```
import time


n = 25
for i in range(n):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    progress = int(i / n * 50)
    print(f'running {i+1} of {n} {progress*"."}', end='\r', flush=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want to use `tqdm` as I stated in the title.